# Exclude files from git diff-tree

Tags: git, bash, git-diff-tree

I execute command:

```
git diff-tree --diff-filter=ACMR --no-commit-id --name-only -r $COMMIT^1.. --
```

from the result I create zip archive.

How can I exclude specific files from the result generated by the above command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can get `diff-tree` to do that for you unless you can specify paths that you are interested in explicitly after the `--`.

But you can post-process that list with `grep`/`sed`/`awk`/etc. at the very least.

Actually, you might be able to use `zip`'s `-x` argument to do the exclusions for you directly in the zipping step as well.

Comment: Thanks for your tips, I have managed to do this with `grep -Ev` at the very least.